# OpenSSH config assign port programmatically?

Tags: openssh

I have a crapboat of less-than-new computers that I've been hooking up to a small compute cluster because why not.  I have a single master node that has a public IP address that these computers can all talk to.  The worker nodes are behind a NAT.  So, in order to converse with them all, I have them all create a reverse ssh tunnel into the master node on boot.  Thus, they are each connected to the master at a different port.  Each machine chooses a port `n+1` where `n` is the previous machine's port number.  In my ssh config on my laptop, I have the following:

```
Host worker*
    ProxyCommand ssh master -W %h:%p
    HostName localhost

Host worker001
    Port 7001
Host worker002
    Port 7002
....
#Host workerX
#    Port 7000 + X
```

What I would like to do, is to have a single entry for my workers, so that workerX uses port 7000 + X.  Is this possible with ssh config?  If not, is there some other workaround to have this happen?  Alternatively, can I "split" my ssh config, so that my `~/.ssh/config` file doesn't have a hundred lines of `workerX`, and I can confine all of that mess?

Answer (score 2):

You're using ProxyCommand, so just write a custom command that does this:

```
ProxyCommand ~/bin/worker-ssh %h
```

Where the script itself might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
host=$1
if [[ $host =~ ^worker0*([0-9]+)$ ]]; then
    port=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    port=$(( port + 7000 ))
    ssh master -W "localhost:$port"
else
    echo "error: $0: host '$host' is not a worker" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

(Do not use `HostName` with this; the proxy command will obviously need to know the original host name.)

Comment: Consider mentioning that `ssh_config` supports the `Include` directive to answer the "Alternatively" part of the question.